# MarshalBinary time.Time: predicting its byte-size

Tags: go, marshalling

TL;DR;

> Can one predict the buffer returned by size time.Time.MarshalBinary() - to assist during binary unmarshaling of other custom types.

---

Trying to write a *compact* [BinaryMarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#BinaryMarshaler) for my type (i.e. avoiding storing unnecessary size-markers):

```
type Item struct {
    t time.Time
    m *pb.Device // implements proto.Message - so use proto.Marshal(...) to Marshal
}
```

Both fields have BinaryMarshaler's so this should be easy. First pass, was to append both marshaled `[]bytes` together (time first, proto.Message second). But how to `Unmarshal`, as [time.Time.UnmarshalBinary](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UnmarshalBinary) does not indicate how many bytes were consumed - so what offset should be used to begin the `proto.Message` unmarshaling?

Checking the [time source](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=35874:35919#L1161) suggests `time.Time.MarshalBinary()` will always return 15 bytes (the first byte holding a algorithm version of `1`). This appears to hold true from go versions `1.2.2` to today (`1.14`).

So can one calculate the number of byte consumed by a `time.UnmarshalBinary` to assist in custom `BinaryUnmarshalers` - and avoid hard-coded assumptions like:

```
func (i *Item) UnmarshalBinary(b []byte) error {
    const (
        timeV     = 1
        timeV1Len = 15
    )
    if len(b) == 0 {
        *i = Item{} // no data - set to zero value
        return nil
    }
    if b[0] != timeV {
        return fmt.Errorf("time.Time binary marshaled at unsupported version %d (expected version %d)", b[0], timeV)
    }
    if len(b) < timeV1Len {
        return fmt.Errorf("data too short: should be >= %d bytes, got %d byte(s)", timeV1Len, len(b))
    }
    if err = i.t.UnmarshalBinary(b[:timeV1Len]); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(b[timeV1Len:]) == 0 {
        i.m = nil // no more data, so set Message nil
        return nil
    }
    i.m = &pb.Device{}
    return proto.Unmarshal(b[timeV1Len:], i.m)
}
```

Comment: No, it will not, because it's not documented to do so. The first byte is even a version marker, reserving the right to change anything and everything about the format in future versions.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the actual implementation code won't change. They could very easily modify that to handle a new version in a backwards compatible way. The whole point of having the version byte is so the format can be changed.

Comment: Agreed. I guess I was remembering Rob Pike's desire to `slice header` under the hood - which would be perfectly within the spec to do - but has not done so cause of applications use of `unsafe`. I would make a large bet that the time format will not change for `go 1.*` - and possibly even `go 2.*` - but will stick with the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the size of the output of `MarshalBinary` is not subject to the [Go 1 Compatibility Promise](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat):

> Unspecified behavior. The Go specification tries to be explicit about most properties of the language, but there are some aspects that are undefined. Programs that depend on such unspecified behavior may break in future releases.

[Time.MarshalBinary](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.MarshalBinary) does not specify the size of its output, so it would be considered an "unspecified behavior".

Comment: …not only the size, but also the contents of such output. I think the OP is better off writting their own serializer/unserializer.

Comment: True, but they only asked about the length, and if they're using `UnmarshalBinary` to read them (which they are in the sample code), it doesn't matter if the contents change.

Comment: It may matter when the unmarshaling code is built by a version of Go (actually its stdlib) different from that of the marshaling, and it happens that them both have different implementations—I mean, when different programs exchange data (say, over the network).

Comment: No, it doesn't; as noted in the question, `Time.MarshalBinary` includes a binary representation version for compatibility between Go stdlib versions.

Comment: Thank you, I stand corrected. (Though it's interesting what happens when an attempt it made to unmarshal a version from the future.)

Comment: @kostix - to your first comment: I think I framed my question too rigidly (I've since edited). It's becoming apparent a custom marshaler for `time.Time` would probably be needed.